# SharePoint Online Change the look Theme not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, themes, sharepoint-online

I am working with a site using the Microsoft Developer Program. I am able to use the new Change the look feature on modern Communication sites to adjust the theme.

I created a theme using Powershell

I created a Communicators site and selected the Custom theme and used a PowerShell cmdlet to set that site as the homepage. I am still able to change the theme on that site by going to `Settings > Change the look > Theme`. The default and custom theme appear in the menu to select.

I attempted to follow the instructions on creating a Site Design to test out the feature of potentially exploring site designs. I ran into some issues of the feature I was attempting to use was not supported yet. I did not create any site designs. I use the `Get_SPOSiteDesign` cmdlet and nothing is returned.

I then created another communications site. I was just going to build these one at a time since Site designs did not meet my goal. I wanted to change the theme to the Custom theme, I go to Settings > Change the look > Theme and it closes the Change the look menu in the panel and returns me to the Settings panel.

I am able to go to Settings > Change the look > Header, Navigation and Footer successfully. Only the Theme option causes this error. I am unable to change the theme.

I used a PowerShell cmdlet to ensure the themes were not hidden, `Set-SPOHideDefaultThemes $false`. This is set.

I then created a second, third a fourth Communications site (using the Topic, Showcase and Blank designs) and the same error above occurs not being able to access the theme menu.

I then created a Team site. I am able to access the Theme and change to the Custom theme or one of the default selections.

I need help as to why new Communication sites I create in my environment will not allow me to access the theme menu, but homesites and team site do allow this. What do I need to do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I too am coming across the same issue. I have attempted it in difference browsers and in incognito to verify it wasn't an extension or browser specific issue. Have you discovered a resolution or opened a ticket yet?

Comment: The sites that have issues have serious Javascript errors generated by Microsoft.

Comment: I did not get a good answer either, but here is a thread from another site i posted, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-change-the-look-theme-not/5698ddcc-2276-40c5-8051-9b09052c745e, with some feedback and work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue on our tenant and have opened a ticket a MS support. They confirmed that this a bug and are going to solve it.

For now we have a workaround via PNP Powershell. 
When you set the theme first via Set-PnPWebTheme -Theme "Custom Theme", the option to modify the theme via the browser works again.